# How to split a list of strings into sublists at every character

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, all with the same length, and I would like to split the list into sublists where every sublist has every character in a seperate string. I am using Python 3.7.4.

eg:

```python
input = ['Hell', 'ello', 'llo ', 'lo W', 'o Wo', ' Wor', 'Worl', 'orld', 'rld!']

output = [['H','e','l','l'],['e','l','l','o'],['l','l','o',' '],...['r','l','d','!']]
```

(shortened the output cause I didn't want to be here all night)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension

```
input = ['Hell', 'ello', 'llo ', 'lo W', 'o Wo', ' Wor', 'Worl', 'orld', 'rld!']
output = [list(s) for s in input]
```

Comment: Thanks! I probably should have figured that out on my own haha, even being pretty new to python